# Calculation Discrepancy using jQuery.height() between window and body

Tags: jquery, dom, pagination, height, infinite-scroll

I am interested in determining when a user has reached the bottom of the page in order to fire off a custom callback event, similar to "infinite scrolling" or "endless scrolling."

My best theory on how to go about this is to first calculate the height of the body element:

`var bodyHeight = $('body').outerHeight();`

Next, measure the height of the window frame:

`var winHeight = $(window).height();`

and lastly determine the vertical scroll position:

`var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();`

However, when I insert this script into the body:

`<script>

    console.log(bodyHeight, winHeight);

    $(window).bind("scroll", function(){

      console.log(winHeight + scrollY);

    });

</script>`

I will often see that the calculated scroll position exceeds the height of the body. I have seen something similar when using OSX with the "elastic scrolling" but this is only using the standard scrollbar ui.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you just stick with $('body').height(), you should be fine.

```
$('body').height() - $(window).height() == $('body').scrollTop()
```

It is possible that you see the scrollTop() is off if you have position:absolute, position:fixed or floated elements. In this case, your body element doesn't actually wrap the tallest element, so it doesn't work.

If that is the case, you can actually use scrollHeight.

```
document.body.scrollHeight - $(window).height() == $('body').scrollTop()
```

It looks like jQuery doesn't have a scrollHeight method (or equivalent) and there are a few browser compatibility issues with it ([W3C Dom Compatibility for scrollHeight](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t36)), but it works in all modern browsers.

Worst case scenario, you could get all elements, loop through them to find the max height and then use that for:

```
var maxHeight = ((function() { var maxHeight = 0; $('*').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max($(this).height(), maxHeight);
}); return maxHeight; })());

maxHeight - $(window).height() == $('body').scrollTop()
```

If you use that approach, I HIGHLY recommend you cache the value and update it only as needed.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeDEu/1/)

Comment: There are no floated elements that are not later cleared, so there should not be any elements collapsing that could affect `bodyHeight`. The core issue is that `winHeight + scrollY` ends up being greater than the calculated .outerHeight() (inclusive to margin, padding, border, if applicable) of the body element, so there is not a reliable way to use a comparison operator to fire the callback only once.  

The difference is negligible, only about 7px, strangely.  

FYI, http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/ is similar to scrollHeight in that it considers padding but not border or margin.

Comment: scrollHeight works regardless of closed elements, because it is using the same value that the scrollbar uses (when it is available). If you could provide some HTML or a browser which causes the mystery issue, we might be able to solve the problem. I'm not sure why you chose outerHeight() vs. height() though.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the solution that I came up with: https://github.com/oomlaut/addPageBottomListener